# API output doesn't show in a TextView

Tags: java, android-studio, android-volley

I tried to make a very simple weather app that shows the temperature of a certain city.

But when I press the button to get the temperature, the text doesn't change.

[Here is what happens if I try to get the temperature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYRYX.png)

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    Button button;
    EditText etCityName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        etCityName = findViewById(R.id.etCityName);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                jsonParse();
            }
        });
    }
    public void jsonParse() {
        String url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + etCityName.getText() + "&appid=token";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) { ;
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("main");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject url = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String temp = url.getString("temp");
                                textView.setText(temp);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
         }
        });
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't post that if I didn't check that.

Comment: My answer comment 15 completed i should be here comment.

Comment: what is 4 item?

Comment: Try logging the temp string in your debug console. Also if you checked the response by printing it?

Comment: org.json.JSONException: No value for temp

Answer (score 0):

use `etCityName.getText().toString`

instead of `etCityName.getText()`  in your jsonparse() method

Comment: That doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: when I tried the url, it showed invalid api key. Do you add token when you call the api

Comment: Yes I did add it.

Comment: can u show me the json output from api

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/H6soT2b

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    Button button;
    EditText etCityName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        etCityName = findViewById(R.id.etCityName);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (etCityName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                 etCityName.setError("Required");
                }else{
                      jsonParse();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void jsonParse() {
        String url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + etCityName.getText().toString().trim() + "&appid=token";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) { ;
                        try {
                                String temp = response.getDouble("temp").toString();
                                textView.setText(temp);
                            
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
         }
        });
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: sadly, that doesnt work too

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244272/discussion-on-answer-by-meet-bhavsar-api-output-doesnt-show-in-a-textview).

Comment: send me api key my code is i will check my code